# Autosys R11 - Throw an alert if a job doesn't start at a specific time

Tags: scheduling, jobs, schedule, autosys, jil

What I need is, for example, if I have a scheduled job (that has a predecessor) that should start at 12:00am, if it hasn't started by 12:10am an alert would be sent..

I can't seem to make it work through JIL code, does anyone know how could I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could create a file when your job starts and then have another job that starts at 12:10 and sends an alert if the file is not there...

Comment: This question is about server management software. Unless you are writing software with the AutoSys SDK, your question should be asked on [sf] instead.

Answer (score 1):

must_start_times is likely the JIL attribute you're looking for.  A description of how must_start_times works starts on page 131 of the [Autosys User Guide](https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20Workload%20Automation%20AE%20Release%2011%203%206%20-%20Public%20Access-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/PDF/WA_AE_User_ENU.pdf)